# how to get username and display when is logged in

Tags: php, html, css

in this i wannna get the username who is logged in and display it in the home page when the username is correct and registered in database .should i use session and where to use it.how it is been done

```js
<?php

error_log("chk.php executing");
// Get values from form 
include 'config.php';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
 error_log($key);
}
//error_log($_POST['username']);
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
// Insert data into mysql 
$qry   = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM useraccount WHERE username='$username'");
if(!$qry) {
    die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
} else {

    $row=mysql_fetch_array($qry);

    if ($username==$row['username']) {
        if($username=='' || $password=='') {
         error_log("some fields are empty");
            //header("Location:login.php?id=Some fields are empty");
            // header("Content-Type: text/html");
   // {echo "<b>Some fields are empty</b>";}
        } else if($username==$row['username'] && $password==$row['password']) {
         error_log("logged in");
         header('Location: home.html');
         // header("Content-Type: text/html");
   // {echo "<b>User name password verified</b>";}
            //header("Location: home.html?id=$username");
        } else {
         error_log("password is incorrect");
         // header("Content-Type: text/html");
   // {echo "<b>username already taken or your password is incorrect. Please try again</b>";}
            //header("Location:.php?id=username already taken or your password is incorrect. Please try again");
        }}
        else
         error_log("username incorrect");
    }
    mysql_close();
?>
```

```css
html,body
{
margin:0px; 
height:100%;
}
 .carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 60%;
      margin: auto;
  }
 .content
 {
width:100%;
height:400px;

 }

 .signup
 {
height:500px;

 }
  .footer
  {
    position:relative;
   background-color:black;
  }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  
  <title>ASK</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="boot.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
         
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h1>school name</h1>
                
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="../project/photo/l.png"  height="150px"/>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div> 

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#mynavbar">schoolName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html" target=_self>About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="infra.html" target=_self>Infrastructure</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="">Administration<span class="caret"></span></a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="stlogin.html">staff login</a></li>
            <li><a href="stdetails.html">staff details</a></li>
            <li><a href="class.html">class handling</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
 <form class="form-horizontal" action="chk.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input name="username" type="username" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter username">
    </div></div>
    
    
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter password">
    </div></div>

    <!-- <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label><br>
    </div> -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button><br>
    
  </form>
  </div>
  <div class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
<p> Copyrights@ &copy;WWW.schools.com</p>
    



</div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: check roytuts.com/php-mysql-login-logout-with-remember-me/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SESSION` . You have to use `session_start()` in every files that you want to display the username

```
    else if($username==$row['username'] && $password==$row['password']) {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username; // store username name in session
                error_log("logged in");
                header('Location: home.html');
                // header("Content-Type: text/html");
                // {echo "<b>User name password verified</b>";}
                header("Location: home.php?id=$username"); // redirect to home.php page
```

You can simply display the username by `echo $_SESSION['username'];` Don't forget to add `session_start();` in your home.php. For more info please refer to this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Answer (score 1):

```
first of all when username store in session on login time 


  <?php

session_start();

 - List item

error_log("chk.php executing"); // Get values from form  include 'config.php';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {    error_log($key); } //error_log($_POST['username']); $username=$_POST['username']; $password=$_POST['password']; // Insert data into mysql  $qry   = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM useraccount WHERE username='$username'"); if(!$qry) { die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error()); } else {

$row=mysql_fetch_array($qry);

if ($username==$row['username']) {
    if($username=='' || $password=='') {
        error_log("some fields are empty");
        //header("Location:login.php?id=Some fields are empty");
        // header("Content-Type: text/html");           // {echo "<b>Some fields are empty</b>";}
    } else if($username==$row['username'] && $password==$row['password']) {
        error_log("logged in");

       $_SESSION['username']=$row['username'];
        header('Location: home.html');
        // header("Content-Type: text/html");           // {echo "<b>User name password verified</b>";}
        //header("Location: home.html?id=$username");
    } else {
        error_log("password is incorrect");
        // header("Content-Type: text/html");           // {echo "<b>username already taken or your password is incorrect. Please try again</b>";}
        //header("Location:.php?id=username already taken or your password is incorrect. Please try again");
    }}
    else
        error_log("username incorrect"); } mysql_close(); ?>
```

Another page we get this username and we change file name home.html to home.php

home.php

echo  $_SESSION['username'];

?>
output username print this page

Comment: You cannot access session another page because you are using html file header('Location: home.html');  to  header('Location: home.php'); then you can access session.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `session_start();`
After successfully login,you can post username or email like this-

```
<?php
include_once'dbconnect.php';
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
//print logged in user's email as saved in database
echo $userRow['email'];
////print logged in user's username as saved in database
echo $userRow['username'];
?>
```

This is as per my database where-

- 'dbconnect.php'is connection file.
- 'users' is tablename.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `session_start();` and store the username into it.

```
//Initialize the session:
session_start();
<!doctype html>
<head>
.
.
.
</head>
<body>
.
.
<?php
$q = "SELECT * FROM useraccount WHERE username='$username'";
$r = $mysqli->query($q);
if ($r->num_rows == 1) {
$_SESSION = $r-> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
}
?>
.
</body>
</html>
```

You can take a look at my site for that same query at `hiteachers.com`

Comment: you have problem at login page after registering i am not able to log in

Comment: @sudharsan it's because you have not activated your account yet. Check your email, including SPAM/JUNK folder for the email with the subject 'New Notification' to activate it.